# How to do multiple searches within a NSData object?

Tags: nsdata, string-matching, aho-corasick

**TL, DR**

See this member function of `NSData` (in Swift here):

```
func rangeOfData(_ dataToFind: NSData, options mask: NSDataSearchOptions, range searchRange: NSRange) -> NSRange
```

I want to replace that first parameter with a `Set` (or other collection) of `NSData` and return the first match.  A data pattern can be a subset of another, so return the longest match.  Any ideas?

I've heard that this method uses something like Boyer–Moore in its implementation. So my extension would probably use something like Aho–Corasick.

**Too long...**

I want to read e-mail files.

I'm planning to read files a line at a time, so I need a line-break detection algorithm.  The standard is CRLF, but I should scan for just-CR, just-LF, and (for completion) LFCR.  Note I'm reading in binary, where binary-to-text is done at a later stage, so all those `NSString` and `NSRegularExpression` stuff won't help me.

I was going to write a custom routine, then I realized I could probably generalize it.  I made a parse-tree node class, a skeleton class of the line generator, and a bunch of tests.  I have procrastinated on the meat of the code: the input byte scanning, creating parse trees, and traversing parse trees.  I'm still procrastinating by looking around here a second time, because this seems like the type of problem our programmer ancestors had to do and already have code for.

This time around, I found out about the string-matching algorithms, so hopefully I'm one step closer (besides translating them to Swift).

Or maybe I should drop generalization and call `rangeOfData: options: range:` in two passes each cycle, one for CR and once for LF and reconcile them.  That's inefficient, though.  Or keep the custom list idea; make a tree with a branch for each pattern, unifying prefix overlaps with a branch with multiple nodes.  (If searching backwards, make suffix-oriented branches!)  Multiple passes here would be even more inefficient.

Note that `NSData` has a function to traverse its data as a series of blocks.  I was going to use that function, but I have to be careful that a pattern could be split across two (or more!) blocks.